# WebVTT to JSON using `jq`

Tags: jq, webvtt

I'd like to convert some WebVTT to JSON.  I have a `jq` filter, but it could be improved.
[jqplay.org example](https://jqplay.org/s/jAHQOeysY-p)

Here's a snippet of example WebVTT.

```
WEBVTT

dc9af9e8-8909-11ee-80b1-44850052397e
00:00:08.280 --> 00:00:08.880
Good morning Mr. Phelps.

ddf6092c-8909-11ee-bc4f-44850052397e
00:00:09.720 --> 00:00:12.840
Your mission, should you choose to
accept it,

e03b2da2-8909-11ee-a212-44850052397e
00:17:52.052 --> 00:17:55.586
This tape will self-destruct in 5
seconds.
```

Using this filter (with `--null-input --raw-input` options),

```
def rtrim: rtrimstr("\r");
input|rtrim|{filename: input_filename, filetype: ., cues:
[foreach inputs as $i
  ( {start:false, theEnd:false};
    if ($i|test("^[a-f0-9]{8}-"))
    then .start=true|.theEnd=false|.out={uid: $i|rtrim, timeline: input|rtrim, subtitles: [input|rtrim]} 
    else
      if ($i|test("^\\s*$"))
      then .theEnd=.start
      else if .start then .out+={subtitles: (.out.subtitles+[$i|rtrim])} else .theEnd=false end
      end
    end;
    if (.start and .theEnd) then [.out] else empty end
  )
| add]
}
```

... the desired output is produced for my example files.

```json
{
  "filename": "<stdin>",
  "filetype": "WEBVTT",
  "cues": [
    {
      "uid": "dc9af9e8-8909-11ee-80b1-44850052397e",
      "timeline": "00:00:08.280 --> 00:00:08.880",
      "subtitles": [
        "Good morning Mr. Phelps."
      ]
    },
    {
      "uid": "ddf6092c-8909-11ee-bc4f-44850052397e",
      "timeline": "00:00:09.720 --> 00:00:12.840",
      "subtitles": [
        "Your mission, should you choose to",
        "accept it,"
      ]
    },
    {
      "uid": "e03b2da2-8909-11ee-a212-44850052397e",
      "timeline": "00:17:52.052 --> 00:17:55.586",
      "subtitles": [
        "This tape will self-destruct in 5",
        "seconds."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`rtrim` is used in case the WebVTT file has DOS `\r\n` line endings.  All `if` statements have an `else` clause since some versions of `jq` require it.

##### Issues

1. Filter requires an extra newline at the end of the file to emit the last cue.
2. Filter is mostly sufficient, but a bit of a mess. It was patched until the desired output appeared.  It could be improved.

I know there are other solutions/libraries/apps to process WebVTT, but I'm curious to know if `jq` can do it on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WebVTT file format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API) allows for many more content items, e.g. text headers, cue settings, `NOTE` blocks, `STYLE` blocks, etc., even a BOM at the beginning. But if you're happy considering only the subset used in your example (backed by your statement that your sample filter produces the desired output), have a look atthe following rewrite:

##### Line endings

> `rtrim` is used in case the WebVTT file has DOS `\r\n` line endings.

You could read the entire input into one string using `jq --raw-input --slurp`, then remove all carriage return characters using `gsub("\r"; "")`, so from then on you only have to deal with newline characters.

##### Final newline

> Filter requires an extra newline at the end of the file to emit the last cue.

To partition the long string into empty-line-delimited blocks, it can be split into an array at any occurrence of at least two consecutive newline characters (i.e. at least one empty line) using the regex `\n\n+`. That way, it doesn't matter if there is no newline at the end. Combine it with the regex `\n$` to also catch (and eliminate) a single newline ending: `splits("\n(\n+|$)")`

##### Output composition

The `first` block of text is considered to be the line containing the `.filetype`, and the remaining items in the `.[1:]` array are the blocks that become the items in the `.cues` array. Use `map` to transform each item by first splitting them again into lines using `/`, then drop any items that had no lines using `select(has(0))`, and distribute the first (`.[0]`), second (`.[1]`) and all remaining lines (`.[2:]`) to `.uid`, `.timeline`, and `.subtitles`, respectively.

```bash
# jq -Rs

gsub("\r"; "") | [splits("\n(\n+|$)")] | {
  filename: input_filename, filetype: first,
  cues: .[1:] | map(. / "\n" | select(has(0)) | {
    uid: .[0], timeline: .[1], subtitles: .[2:]
  })
}
```

```json
{
  "filename": "<stdin>",
  "filetype": "WEBVTT",
  "cues": [
    {
      "uid": "dc9af9e8-8909-11ee-80b1-44850052397e",
      "timeline": "00:00:08.280 --> 00:00:08.880",
      "subtitles": [
        "Good morning Mr. Phelps."
      ]
    },
    {
      "uid": "ddf6092c-8909-11ee-bc4f-44850052397e",
      "timeline": "00:00:09.720 --> 00:00:12.840",
      "subtitles": [
        "Your mission, should you choose to",
        "accept it,"
      ]
    },
    {
      "uid": "e03b2da2-8909-11ee-a212-44850052397e",
      "timeline": "00:17:52.052 --> 00:17:55.586",
      "subtitles": [
        "This tape will self-destruct in 5",
        "seconds."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/H1CUGv_8Tco)

Comment: Works great, and very clear/concise.  Yes, I am fortunate (?) my files have this small subset of WebVTT format elements.

Comment: FYI, using your answer as a template, I found [this](https://jqplay.org/s/RpDroB0PK1w) to go about twice as fast on my large files.

Comment: Using `split/2` to enable the regex parser while creating an array is clever. Also, carrying `\r` into the splits saves you from going through the input twice.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [@pmf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77532165/1409374) - it's clear and concise.  For very large files (e.g. from hours of interviews, documentaries), making a single pass through the file will speed up the processing considerably.

Below is a much improved filter (compared to the one in the question), that uses a small FIFO to collect each cue, and then emit it when there's a line break.  A problem with this filter and an input file that has no trailing newlines, is that the last cue won't get emitted on its own.  To workaround that, some newlines can be appended to `jq`'s input stream.  Here's how I did that using input file process substitution:

```
$ jq the_options the_filter the_WebVTT_file <(echo -e "\n")
```

Improved filter (using `--null-input --raw-input`):

```
input | rtrimstr("\r") |
{
  filename: input_filename,
  filetype: .,
  cues: [
    foreach inputs as $i
      ( {fifo:[], emit: false};
        if .emit then .emit=false|.fifo=[] else . end |
        if ($i|test("^\\s*$")) and (.fifo|length > 0)
        then .emit=true
        else
          if ($i|test("^\\s*$")|not)
          then .fifo+=[$i|rtrimstr("\r")]
          else .
          end
        end;
        if .emit then {uid:.fifo[0], timeline:.fifo[1], subtitles:.fifo[2:] } else empty end
      )
  ]
}
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/hvVqz836ZYB).